# How get Gorm Query Count Result

Tags: go, go-gorm, glide-golang

I want to get rows count for the selected user. I used gorm library. There is no any full example to identify how get count from the selected table.

```
row = m.DB.Raw("SELECT count(*) as count FROM user_advertisement_categories uac  WHERE uac.user_id = ?", userId).Row()
```

Gorm's given example doesn't explain how assign count variable. I want to check is there a record in the table for the given user.

Can anyone give me an example code how should I check the user count and if it isn't a record for the user? I should insert and if there was a user in the table I think,I should delete those records and insert new array.

I get a category array for user.

Answer (score 10):

You can assign the count to a variable as follow:

```
count := 0
db.Model(&User{}).Where("uac.user_id = ?", "userId").Count(&count)
```

Where **User** struct is the one related to the **user_advertisement_categories** table.

See at Gorm documentation for more details: http://gorm.io/docs/query.html

Comment: How get the count variable. Should I use Scan

Comment: The count variable initialized on first instruction on my answer is updated on the second one within the result of the query